# Azure Function Adding Reference to Sharepoint.dll Failing

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint-2013, azure-functions

I am getting an error when I attempt to add a reference to the Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll into my Azure function class. It keeps giving me the following error:

Package Sharepoint 15.0.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NetFramework, Version=v4.6.2). Package Sharepoint 15.0.0 supports microsoftsharepoint (Microsoft.SharePoint,version=v0.0).

Also the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime has a similar issue.

Given this I have followed other advice to switch the targeting framework to 4 and 4.5 but all of these seem to fail similarly. What is the supported framework for this and how can I add it into an azure function. Also I am dealing with an on-prem instance of sharepoint so I cannot connect via the online apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.dll/15.0.0) have no dependencies so, it it no matter with framework. I test in my site and could install it correctly.

You could try to use the `Package Manager console` in Visual Studio to install instead of the Manager Packages tool for the project.

And if you use `Manage Nuget Packages`, delete Nuget's cache from the packages' manager configuration.

Comment: Thanks @joey-cai I ended up using the sharepoint online nuget package and it seems that this also works for on prem.